# Where do I find the original site for a site that was renamed?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I changed the URL of a sharepoint online site, but now I need to change it back to the original URL.  Neither the admin portal nor the Powershell command (Set-SPSiteURL) allows this because the original URL is still taken somewhere.  If I do a Get-SPOSite on the original URL, the site comes up, with the owner as SHAREPOINT\system.  However this site is not listed in the admin portal in Active sites or Deleted sites.  I don't see anything in the recycle bin of the renamed site.  Where else could I look to find this site?  Additionally, does SP actually make a copy of the site when the URL is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you move a SharePoint site, it creates a stub site at the original URL using the REDIRECTSITE#0 template.

You can use `Remove-SPOSite` to remove the redirected stub site. You may need to wait a bit, but you should then be able to move your site back to the original URL.

More information on how to manage these site types is available at [Manage site redirects](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/manage-site-redirects)